JavaFX WebEngine: Can not set user-agent header
I am trying to add new headers in requests/responses of webpages that are displayed in WebView.
After research, I found that the easy way to add headers is to set the user-agent header.
My problem that it is working on Desktop (Linux) but it is not working on Android and iOS.
First, "getUserAgent()" method is returning null !
Second, "setUserAgent()" is not working on Android and iOS devices

”I found that the easy way to add headers is to set the user-agent header” -> setting the user agent header has nothing to do with setting other headers in requests and responses.  What other “new headers in requests and responses” do you want and why?  You could edit the question to add a desired network trace, similar to a verbose curl output that includes that exact header values you want to add.

I want to send some data/tokens to the backend. and for some limitations, currently, the available way to send those tokens is to add them the the request headers.
I tried many ways, until i found this https://x.com/CodingFabian/status/524942996748652544
this is how the user-agent can be used to add new request headers. and it is working for me in Linux env. but not working when I use GluonFX to run on Android and iOS mobiles

That twitter post: webEngine.setUserAgent("foo\nHeader: value") is just a ridiculous hack.

But I saw it worked using Desktop
But overall.  Then how can I add new headers to my requests :) which can be working on Desktop, Android, iOS

That’s a different question.  Perhaps you could use a CookieManager to set cookies instead. It isn’t the same as setting an arbitrary header, but that is the standard way to send additional data from a client to a server with each request.  Don’t know if it would apply in your case or not.

Thank you @jewelsea , I will check the the backend owner to do that. seems that adding a new header is not as easy as i though
